# Convert a decimal day of the year to a timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, decimal

How can I convert a decimal representation of a day in the year to a timestamp with all the parts, both the full date and the time?

For example, my first decimal is `22.968530853511766` and I want it in a nice timestamp format.

Comment: So what does `22.968530853511766` translate to? The 22 second day of this year?

Comment: so Jan 22nd, 0.968 -> 11:58pm, roughly?

Answer (score 10):

Use a [`timedelta()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) with your value as the `days` parameter; add it to midnight December 31st of the previous year:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

epoch = datetime(datetime.now().year - 1, 12, 31)
result = epoch + timedelta(days=your_decimal)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> epoch = datetime(datetime.now().year - 1, 12, 31)
>>> epoch + timedelta(days=22.968530853511766)
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 22, 23, 14, 41, 65743)
>>> print(epoch + timedelta(days=22.968530853511766))
2015-01-22 23:14:41.065743
```

A `datetime` object can be formatted any number of ways with the [`datetime.strftime()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime); I relied on the default `str()` conversion as called by `print()` in the demo.

Comment: or `datetime(datetime.now().year, 1, 1) + timedelta(days)`. It is not clear whether "decimal day of the year" is `0`-based. It seems we already had this conversation.