# Rounding datetime to the nearest hour

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I have a question very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691545/python-convert-days-since-1990-to-datetime-object) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490352/convert-a-decimal-day-of-the-year-to-a-timestamp) but I'm stuck on some rounding issue.

I have a time series from a netCDF file and I'm trying to convert them to a datetime format. The format of the time series is in 'days since 1990-01-01 00:00:00'. Eventually I want output in the format `.strftime('%Y%m%d.%H%M')`. So for example I read my netCDF file as follows

```
import netCDF4
nc = netCDF4.Dataset(file_name)
time = np.array(nc['time'][:])
```

I then have

```
In [180]: time[0]
Out[180]: 365
In [181]: time[1]
Out[181]: 365.04166666651145
```

I then did

```
In [182]: start = datetime.datetime(1990,1,1)
In [183]: delta = datetime.timedelta(time[1])
In [184]: new_time = start + delta
In [185]: print(new_time.strftime('%Y%m%d.%H%M'))
19910101.0059
```

Is there a a way to "round" to the nearest hour so I get `19910101.0100`?

Comment: What does `365.04166666651145` represents?

Comment: Days since 1990-01-01 00:00:00 @GarbageCollector

Comment: Since then to today? No it isn't... There are much better ways to get "days since"

Comment: And how do you define "nearest hour"? 29 mins rounds down? 30 minutes rounds up?

Comment: I got the time (in days) from a netCDF file as initially stated. This is a quite common dateformat in netCDF datasets. Output in the netCDF file is hourly (e.g. `365, 365.04166666651145, 365.08333333348855` etc.) but when loading the file there is some rounding error somewhere. So I shouldn't have to deal with rounding minutes - it'll just be a matter of rounding the milliseconds up/down. I edited the original question to clarify where `time` comes from.

Comment: If one is using `pandas`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40392278/6131611)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can round down with [`datetime.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace), and round up by adding an hour to the rounded down value using [`datetime.timedelta(hours=1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

```
import datetime

def round_to_hour(dt):
    dt_start_of_hour = dt.replace(minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    dt_half_hour = dt.replace(minute=30, second=0, microsecond=0)

    if dt >= dt_half_hour:
        # round up
        dt = dt_start_of_hour + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
    else:
        # round down
        dt = dt_start_of_hour

    return dt
```

Note that since we're using `replace` the values we're not replacing (like the timezone - `tzinfo`) will be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `datetime` provides a way to round times, you'll have to provide the code to do that yourself. Something like this should work:

```
def round_to_hour(dt):
    round_delta = 60 * 30
    round_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dt.timestamp() + round_delta)
    round_dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(round_timestamp)

    return round_dt.replace(microsecond=0, second=0, minute=0)
```

Comment: minor bug with this - currently this will discard tzinfo